# Typeorm suddenly can't import statement outside module import { __awaiter, __generator } from "tslib"

Tags: node.js, typeorm, ts-node

I was using typeorm normally in my project with everything working migrations, generate, run, etc...

Suddenly after creating an new Entity class and trying to generate the migration ts-node has show this error:

```text
➜  untitled git:(master) ✗ yarn typeorm migration:run                                              
yarn run v1.22.10
$ ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
Error during migration run:
/home/pedro/programacao/wazeshop/untitled/node_modules/typeorm/browser/index.js:1
import { __awaiter, __generator } from "tslib";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pedro/programacao/wazeshop/untitled/src/model/Categoria.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Even when using ts-node properly configured.

package.json

```json
{
   "name": "untitled",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "main": "index.js",
   "license": "MIT",
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/node": "^8.0.29",
      "ts-node": "3.3.0",
      "typescript": "3.3.3333"
   },
   "dependencies": {
      "pg": "^8.6.0",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
      "typeorm": "0.2.32"
   },
   "scripts": {
      "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
      "typeorm": "ts-node node_modules/typeorm/cli.js"
   }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true
   }
}
```

Someone know how to stop this error from happening?

Update 1:
After investigating for a bit, I noticed that `yarn typeorm` works normally, but when trying to run a migration or generating a new one the error continue to happen.
[image]